# The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec

Tags: flutter

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service
```

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:

> Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI http:

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2191:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2122:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84:59)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http:", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http:", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/zygote  ( 5217): Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote  ( 5217): After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote  ( 5217): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/flutter ( 5217): 0
```

Comment: presumably your URL should look something like `http://someserver.somedomain/somefolder/someimage.png`. Does it? Can you print it, or show how you derive it?

Comment: According to the stack trace, the URL that you are trying to load is "http:", which justifies the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`No host specified in URI` errors are usually thrown when Flutter is unable to resolve the provided source for the NetworkImage. Ensure that the URL is valid. You can try using [mock image URLs](https://picsum.photos/) to see if either the NetworkImage or the image source causes the issue.